# Forma más eficaz para consultar Array de strings anidado en Array de objetos - Mongoose Nodejs

Tags: javascript, nodejs, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

estoy intentando realizar una consulta a través de mongoose.

El documento al que tengo que acceder pertenece a un modelo con la siguiente estructura:

```
const Schema2 = new Schema({
    name: String,
    data1: [String]
}, { _id: false });

const Schema1 = new Schema({
    ...                                //-> Otros elementos de Schema1 que no influyen
    melocotones: [Schema2]
});
```

Un ejemplo de documento para Schema 1, **y resultado esperado**, sería:

```
{
    ...                                //-> Otros elementos de Schema1 que no influyen 
    "melocotones" : [
        {
            "data1" : [
                "ejemplo_dato1", "ejemplo_dato2", "ejemplo_datoN"
            ]
            "name" : "nombre de ejemplo"
        }
    ]
}
```

No entiendo cual es la forma de acceso para obtener el documento de Schema1 filtrando por los campos data1 y data2 que encontramos en Schema2.

Es decir, mi necesidad es poder filtrar un Array de strings que a su vez se encuentra en un Array de objetos.

¿Cuáles son las formas para poder realizar esta consulta? ¿Cuál es más eficaz?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

---

**Edito para dar mas contexto**

Supongamos que en vez de estar almacenado en una BBDD de mongo lo que tenemos es un Array de objetos de JS, lo que haría sería lo siguiente:

```
for(let schema1 of schemas1){
   for(let schema2 of schema1.melocotones){
      if(schema2.data1 === LOQUEBUSCO){
         return schema1
      }
   }
}
```

También se podría obtener esto con forEach y de otras formas, pero creo que se entiende la intención.

Es decir, necesito obtener el Schema1 completo, en base al campo Schema1.melocotones[N].data1

Comment: Has expuesto la estructura claramente, pero ¿qué quieres obtener o filtrar? Entiendo que con `objetoDeSchema1.melocotones` obtienes el array de objetos de la clase `Schema2`

Comment: Lo que necesito obtener de resultado sería un documento completo de Schema1. Es decir, tengo cientos de documentos Schema1, tengo que filtrar en base al campo Schema1.melocotones[n].data1. Es decir, si el campo data1/data2 es igual a X, que me devuelva el documento Schema1. Edito la pregunta de como lo obtendría si fuese un Array de objetos de JS en vez de documentos de mongo para dar más contexto y entiendas lo que estoy intentando obtener.

Comment: @PabloLozano he actualizado la pregunta a ver si puedo arrojar más luz a que entiendas lo que necesito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola he dado con la tecla a través de la siguiente query:

```
Model.find({  
   melocotones: {
     $elemMatch: {
       data1: loquebusco
     }
   }     
})
```

Adjunto link a la documentación sobre parámetro $elemMatch: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/